# Psycopg2 not inserting list of strings in correct format

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert a list of strings, along with other variable types, into a PostgreSQL database.

As it explains in the psycop2 documentation, I'm doing

```
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO dbname (url, list, num) VALUES ('%s',%s,%s)''' % (url, myList, number))
```

I get an error the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "["
```

I printed out the string I am executing, and psycopg2 writes the list with brackets, which throws the error—it should be `{}`.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Postgres 9.

Comment: Avoid SQL injections! Try: `cur.execute('''INSERT INTO dbname (url, list, num) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)''', (url, myList, number))`

Comment: are quotes correct?`('%s',%s,%s)`

Comment: As pault says, don't format yourself using %. psycopg2 does this for you. And also as mad_ says the quotes are not needed.

Comment: @pault switching the `%` for a `,` worked! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While passing a formatted string will work in many cases, it will leave you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. The preferred way is to pass the string with placeholders and let Psycopg2 do the parameterization.

In short, change your `%` to a comma and remove the quotes around the first placeholder:

```
cur.execute(
    '''INSERT INTO dbname (url, list, num) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)''',
    (url, myList, number)
)
```